# Getting around only having one of the same pseudo elements

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I'm trying to create something like this

[image]

Here the ribbon in the middle is an image. And the gradients surrounding it should be made with CSS.

My goal for this is to have an element to be the title on a page and for this displayed under that title. The code being something like this.

```
    <h1 class="page-title">This is a Title</h1>
```

So by adding that class to the h1, the image would be displayed underneath.
I was trying something like this.

```
    h1.page-title {
      display: block;
    }
    h1.page-title::after {
      content: url(./path/to/image);
      display: block;
    }
```

This did what I was trying to do by adding the image under but I don't know how to add the gradients since multiple pseudo after elements can't be added.

I would like to be able to do this with one HTML tag but I could also not figure this out with two tags. Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: 
This is what I'm trying to get the end product to look like

[image]

Comment: Here is an simplified example of what you could do https://jsfiddle.net/7qpgv5am/ you can see the image is above the blue line, except the image is a png so it is transparent but you can make the image a jpg with space around the icon to create what you want. Or you can just use more elements to make it easier to make what you need

Comment: This is awesome! Thanks, while I'll probably need the image to be transparent I think there is a way to make a gradient like that stops.

Answer (score 0):

With before and after pseudo elements we can turn a single DOM element into 3.

What you are going to want to do is set the background image on the h1 element itself and use your ::before and ::after pseudo elements for your lines.

Here is the CSS I came up with:

```
h1.page-title {
      position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
      background-image: url('https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/red-ribbon-picture-id473856462?k=6&m=473856462&s=612x612&w=0&h=VMdTIdIJCbQ8CjHmb90ywhRB561z_XKx09eI6qJXMF0=');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
    }
.page-title:before,
.page-title:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 5px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid blue;
  top: 0;
  width: 300px;
}
.page-title:before {
  right: 100%;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.page-title:after {
  left: 100%;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

Note: I did not do a gradient with the lines like your example, this is just a simple example to show you how to accomplish with a single div. You will need to adjust the CSS to suit.

Comment: They are called pseudo-elements. Pseudo-classes are a different things. There is a reason two colons are used for pseudo-elements now and not just one anymore.

Comment: This is really close to what I'm trying to do but with using this with the background image it is behind the text(z) and not under it(y) (i can understand that is confusing) but also the space between the surrounding lines are always the width of the text but should be width of the image.

Comment: The edit above has an image of what I'm trying to accomplish and thank you for the help!

Comment: You can position the background image to where you want it

Comment: @Huangism true, but that doesn't solve the other problem with this method

Comment: @McD if you an create an example of this on jsfiddle.net it would be easier to work on what you want

Answer (score 0):

I am referring this [Site1](https://css-tricks.com/examples/GradientBorder) [Site2](https://css-tricks.com/examples/GradientBorder/)

With the help of `position: sticky;`, `z-index: 10;` and `hr` tag i have coded below example,

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
/* https://css-tricks.com/examples/GradientBorder/*/

hr.style-six {
padding: 0;
border: none;
height: 1px;
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,0.75), rgba(0,0,0,0));
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,0.75), rgba(0,0,0,0));
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,0.75), rgba(0,0,0,0));
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,0.75), rgba(0,0,0,0));
color: #333;
text-align: center;
    position: sticky;
    width: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
}


.img{
    background: #fff url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/wikimania2014/thumb/e/e2/Ask-Logo-Small.jpg/250px-Ask-Logo-Small.jpg) no-repeat center;
    background-size: 25px 25px;
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
    position: sticky;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    z-index: 10;
}

.main{
    height: 50px;
    position: relative;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="main">
  <div class="img"></div>
  <hr class="style-six"/>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: While this creates what I did want to create. My goal was to be able to add one class to a single html element and that created image would be under that specific element. This is just two tags that output the image.